# Weird list formatting with xwatermark and refstepcounter

Tags: indentation, counters, xwatermark

I discovered some weird behaviour with `xwatermark` and `\refstepcounter` which I cannot explain. I created a list and the indentation of the first item is correct, but all others are too much indented. If instead `\stepcounter` is used, it's working again. Also if the `xwatermark` package is not loaded. The question is not how to fix this, but why this happens. The package `xwatermark` is not supposed to influence the layout in any way. And the connection to `\refstepcounter` is completely incomprehensible to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\ta}{\refstepcounter{num} \makebox[10mm][l]{\Roman{num})}test\\
  \hspace*{185,5mm}
  \begin{minipage}{15mm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\begin{document}
  Test

  \ta
  \ta
  \ta
\end{document}
```

[image: only first item aligned correctly with xwatermark loaded or refstepcounter used instead]

```
     *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
xwatermark.sty    2012/10/23 v1.5.2d A dynamic watermarking scheme (Ahmed Musa)

catoptions.sty    2012/11/22 v0.2.7f Securing catcodes and parsing options (AM)

  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 picture.sty    2009/10/11 v1.3 Dimens for picture macros (HO)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
fancyhdr.sty    
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
 ltxkeys.sty    2012/11/17 v0.0.3c A robust key-value parser (AM) (Ahmed Musa)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
    Test.xwm
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: Your code was missing the `totcount` package; I added it. I hope it's OK.

Comment: No such weird indentation to declare, here. Have you trie updating your TeX distribution?

Comment: I get no strange output. Can you add what you get by adding `\listfiles` at the top of the example? You'll find the file listing in the log file.

Comment: I can confirm Jubobs' and egreg's result; no problem with indentation here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just removed `totcount` and changed `newtotcounter` to `newcounter`, the problem still occurs like this.

Comment: @Jubobs et al, I tried lualatex and pdflatex on both miktex and texlive (just now updated), file saved as UTF8 and ANSI, always with the same result.

Comment: Ok, file list is attached to original post.

Comment: Ok guys, please try again - I put the `}` after `\end{minipage}` to the next line (cleaning up the code actually "fixed" it). Now you should also see what I mean.

Comment: Remove the space before `\makebox`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, there are many ways to fix this, but it was quite a pain to isolate the problem. I just found it really strange that these packages interact with each other where they shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is subtle. With `xwatermark`, also `hyperref` is loaded (I don't know why, actually). Since `hyperref` redefines `\refstepcounter`, the space after it becomes significant and it's not removed at the line break, because it comes after a node inserted by `hyperref` for the anchor relative to the stepped counter.

Solution: remove the offending space.

```
\newcommand{\ta}{\refstepcounter{num}\makebox[10mm][l]{\Roman{num})}test\\
  \hspace*{185,5mm}
  \begin{minipage}{15mm}
  \end{minipage}
}
```